# Weird error in Firebug for AngularJS regarding ng-options

Tags: angularjs, firebug

When I use Angular's ng-options I get this weird error:

```
Error: [ngOptions:iexp] Expected expression in form of '_select_ (as _label_)? for (_key_,)?_value_ in _collection_' but got 'playlist.id as playlist.name in playlists | orderBy: 'playlist''. Element: <select class="ng-pristine ng-valid" name="playlist" ng-model="playlist" ng-options="playlist.id as playlist.name in playlists | orderBy: 'playlist'">
```

My code is:

```
<select name="playlist" ng-model="playlist" ng-options="playlist.id as playlist.name in playlists | orderBy: 'playlist'"></select>
<button class="btn btn-branded" ng-click="postSongToPlaylist(playlist.id);">Save</button>
```

ng-model is referring to this file:

```
    MediaService.getPlaylists().then(function (response) {
        $scope.playlists = response.data.data;
    });

    $scope.postSongToPlaylist = function(playlist_id) {
        media = {
            id: $rootScope.song_id
        };
        MediaService.postSongToPlaylist(playlist_id, media).then(function (response) {});
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct syntax is `playlist.id as playlist.name for playlist in playlists | ...`